# hibernate validator throws exception ValidationException: HV000028 for @Past annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, validation

I am validating an entity with a hibernate validator in a spring boot project. I got an exception for the Date validator @Past . I faced `javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call`

This is the dependency I have in my gradle.build file

`implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'`

The following my a similar entity I have

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
  
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    @NotEmpty(message = "ENTER REQUIRED FIELDS - FIRST NAME")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    @NotEmpty(message = "ENTER REQUIRED FIELDS - LAST NAME")
    private String lastName; 
    @Column(name = "BIRTH_DATE")
    @Past(message = "PLEASE ENTER A VALID DATE ")
    private Date birthDate;    

}
```

This is a log trace

````
2020-10-25 13:09:11.421 DEBUG 21952 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for anyone having the same issue as mine. My issue was the Date objects were from java.sql.Date. I changed them to java.util.Date now the validation works.

Answer (score 0):

I Quickly ran on my sample project where everything was already configured i think that Date format is the issue. Available default formats are

- yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX
- yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
- EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz
- yyyy-MM-dd

Here is how i have done it

Controller

```java
@PostMapping(value = "test-person")
    public TestPerson testPerson(@Valid @RequestBody TestPerson testPerson) {
        return testPerson;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    public static class TestPerson {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;

        @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
        @NotEmpty(message = "ENTER REQUIRED FIELDS - FIRST NAME")
        private String firstName;
        @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
        @NotEmpty(message = "ENTER REQUIRED FIELDS - LAST NAME")
        private String lastName;
        @Column(name = "BIRTH_DATE")
        @Past(message = "PLEASE ENTER A VALID DATE ")
        @NotNull
        private Date birthDate;

    }

    @ControllerAdvice
    public static class RestExceptionHandler {

        @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
        public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptionMethod(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, WebRequest requset) {
//             general response dump
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors());
        }
    }
```

Also make sure that for `birthDate` you should not use `@NotEmpty` instead use `@NotNull` because for `NotEmpty`

```
length of character sequence is evaluated
```